# Laravel: Migrations

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, migrations

Tô com uma dúvida sobre Migrations do Laravel e acredito que possam me ajudar.

1 - Criei um model com a migration pelo `php artisan make:model Evento -m;`

2 - Além do increments e do timestamps adicionei mais um campo à migration: `$table->string('nome');`

3 - Rodei o comando `php artisan migrate;`

Minha dúvida é,
depois que rodei a php artisan migrate a tabela foi criada no banco de dados. E se por acaso eu precise adicionar mais uma coluna na tabela no banco, como devo proceder em relação à respectiva migration do laravel? Devo fazer direto no banco ou existe um comando pela migration?

Answer (score 6):

Após você ter criado uma migration e ainda queira adicionar um novo campo, você pode proceder da seguinte forma:

Execute o comando `php artisan make:migration alter_table_model`

Com esse comando sera criado um arquivo de nova migration na pasta `database/migration`.

Você deve adicionar no metodo `up` a seguinte linha de código:

```
Schema::table('nome da tabela',function($t){
   $t->string('novo_campo')->nullable();
});
```

No método down:

```
Schema::table('nome da tabela',function($t){
       $t->dropColumn('novo_campo');
    });
```

Em seguida basta executar o comando `php artisan migrate`

Agora você perceberá que a migration criou um novo campo na tabela informada.

Caso queira criar um novo campo sem ter que criar uma nova migration, 
você poderá executar `php artisan migrate:rollback` para voltar a tabela do banco de dados ao estado anterior, editar o arquivo da migration e executar novamente `php artisan migrate` para novas mudanças.

**Observação:** Ao executar o rollback o método chamado é o `down`. Então você sempre deve criar este método de forma a reverter o que foi criado no método `up`.

Comment: Miguel, toda vez que eu executo um "php artisan migrate", mesmo tento uma outra migrate "alter_table_model", o comando recria todo o banco novamente. Isso é um problema se eu já tiver dados no banco de dados, não?

Answer (score 0):

Fala David, tudo bom?

O migration também da suporte para alterações de schema, não só criação.

Uma ótima biblioteca para facilitar isso é **Laravel Generators**

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Exemplo do comando:

`php artisan generate:migration add_user_id_to_posts_table`

Ele irá criar migration para você adicionando o campo `user_id`para tabela `posts`. Show né?

Esta biblioteca é uma facilidade imensa, ela gera todos os scaffold.

Precisando da um toque!

Abraços.

Comment: Tudo bem Junior. Acho esse lance de Migration bem complicado. Up e Down, migrate e migrate:rollback. Talvez seja o caso apenas de encontrar um bom tutorial. Mas por enquanto essa é a única questão que para mim, referente ao Laravel, ainda não está bem esclarecida. Você conhece algum tutorial detalhado sobre Migrations? Abraço.

Comment: @DavidCoelho https://laracasts.com/search?q=migration&q-where=lessons recomendo.

Comment: Essa biblioteca é para o Laravel 4

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim. Mas nativamente tem geração de migrations. Só executar `php artisan make:migration nome`

Answer (score 0):

É só utilizar o comando **php artisan migrate:refresh** depois de alterar seu arquivo migrate.

Ele fará um *rollback* das suas tabelas, e irá recria-las.